# Python Fill in the Blanks game Giving incorrect answer

Tags: python

```
 easy_game = 'Hello welcome to my game \n Lets start off with some easy     questions about the Python programming language. \n This is a placeholder     that allows to attach a name to something __1__. \n A __2__ uses \"\" or \'\' to allow the program to know what it is. \n When using the + sign you do this __3__ to variables. __4__ are symbols that are used to calculate or assign values to variables. '
easy_answers = [ 'variables',
             'string',
             'concatenate',
             'operators' ]

medium_game = 'Hello welcome to my game \n Lets start off with some   medium questions about the Python programming language. A __1__ operator allows you to divide a numeric value and return the remainder. When there is an error in your program the way you fix it is to \n __2__ your program. \n This is the error you will recieve if you misspell or forget soemthing that \n makes it impossible for the program to compile : __3__ error \n There are different types of these but they all iterate through your program : __4__'
medium_answers = [ 'modulus',
               'debug',
               'syntax',
               'loops']

 hard_game = 'Hello welcome to my game \n Lets start off with some hard questions about the Python Programing language. \n This type of loop will continue to run as long as it is true: __1__ \n When using a comparison this is used to say not equal to : __2__ \n Creating a __3__ also creates certain methods inside it. When creating a \n function you may have to pass something into the parentheses. \n This is called passing in an : __4__. '
hard_answers = ['while',
            '!=',
            'class',
            'argument']

def select_difficulty():
     print "\n Please choose a difficulty. The three options you can    choose from are \n Easy , Medium, Hard"
     choice = raw_input().lower()
     return choice

def get_q_a(difficulty):
    if difficulty=="easy":
        return (easy_game, easy_answers)
    if difficulty=="medium":
        return (medium_game,medium_answers)
    if difficulty=="hard":
        return (hard_game,hard_answers)

def play_game(questions,answers):
    print questions
    user_input = raw_input("\n Please answer the questions in Order")
    if user_input == answers[0]:
        questions = questions.replace('__1__', answers[0])
    if user_input != answers[0]:
        user_input = raw_input("\n Incorrect Please answer the questions in Order")
    print questions
    user_input += raw_input("\n Please answer second question")
    if user_input == answers[1]:
        questions += questions.replace('__2__', answers[1])
    if user_input != answers[1]:
        user_input = raw_input("\n Incorrect Please answer the questions again")
    print questions
    user_input += raw_input("\n Please answer the Third question ")
    if user_input == answers[2]:
        questions += questions.replace('__3__', answers[2])
    if user_input != answers[3]:
        user_input = raw_input("\n Incorrect Please answer the questions again")
    print questions
    user_input += raw_input("\n Please answer the fourth question")
    if user_input == answers[3]:
       questions += questions.replace('__4__', answers[3])
       print "congradulations"
    if user_input != answers[3]:
       user_input = raw_input("\n Incorrect Please answer the question again")





def start_game():
    difficulty = select_difficulty()
    answers , questions = get_q_a(difficulty)
    play_game(answers, questions)

start_game()
```

So I am new to python and programming in general. I am trying to make a fill in the blanks game as practice. I came up with this program but for some reason I keep getting errors when ever I answer the second question. It continues to say the answer is incorrect even though its the right answer. Any help would be greatly appreciated as to how I could correct this/how I could make the code better. Thank you in advance for the help.

Comment: Why do you keep adding to user_input? `user_input += raw_input(` ??

Comment: I was under the impression that I had to do that in order to answer different questions. To assign the variable to a new raw_input in order to check if its equal to the answer[ ].

Comment: Don't add to the user input; replace it.  Just remove `+` in those cases.